# Android OpenGL: texture and color problem

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to make a cube that changes color, and at the same time shows a texture. the texture is white with transparent background. The problem is that right now the white part of the image appears transparent showing the color of the cube and the background appears black (color that does not exist in the image). Can someone help?

Cube.java

```
private static Context context;

private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
private FloatBuffer mNormalBuffer;
private ShortBuffer mIndexBuffer;
private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;
private int numberOfindex = 36;
private int textureId;

private int colorIndex = 0;
private int colorTimer = 0;
private int colorWait = 5;
private int colorCant = 360;
private double colorJump = 360.0 / (colorCant * 1.0);
private int[] colors = new int[colorCant];

public Cube(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    float x = 1.0f;
    float y = 1.0f;
    float z = 1.0f;

    float[] vertices = {
            x, y, z, -x, y, z, -x, -y, z, x, -y, z,
            x, y, z, x, -y, z, x, -y, -z, x, y, -z,
            x, y, z, x, y, -z, -x, y, -z, -x, y, z,
            -x, y, z, -x, y, -z, -x, -y, -z, -x, -y, z,
            -x, -y, -z, x, -y, -z, x, -y, z, -x, -y, z,
            x, -y, -z, -x, -y, -z, -x, y, -z, x, y, -z
    };

    float[] normals = {
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0,
            0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0,
            0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1
    };

    float[] textures = {
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
    };

    short indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,
            4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7,
            8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11,
            12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,
            16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,
            20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23
    };

    mVertexBuffer = makeFloatBuffer(vertices);
    mNormalBuffer = makeFloatBuffer(normals);
    mIndexBuffer = makeShortBuffer(indices);
    mTextureBuffer = makeFloatBuffer(textures);
    textureId = loadTexture(gl);

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        colors[i] = Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{(float) (colorJump * i), 1.0f, 1.0f});
    }
}

public static final FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float[] arr) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    fb.put(arr);
    fb.position(0);
    return fb;
}

public static final ShortBuffer makeShortBuffer(short[] arr) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    ShortBuffer fb = bb.asShortBuffer();
    fb.put(arr);
    fb.position(0);
    return fb;
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mNormalBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
    gl.glColor4f((Color.red(colors[colorIndex])) / 255.0f, (Color.green(colors[colorIndex])) / 255.0f, (Color.blue(colors[colorIndex])) / 255.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numberOfindex, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);

    colorTimer++;
    if (colorTimer < colorWait) {
        colorTimer++;
    } else {
        colorTimer = 0;
        if (colorIndex < colors.length - 1) {
            colorIndex++;
        } else {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static final int loadTexture(GL10 gl) {
    int[] textures = new int[1];

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img_cube, options);
    if (bmp == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    bmp.recycle();

    return textures[0];
}
```

MyGLRenderer.java

```
Context context;
Cube cube;

private float[] lightAmbient = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f};
private float[] lightDifuse = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f};
private float[] lightPosition = {-5.0f, 10.0f, -20.0f, 1.0f};

private float cubeAngleY = 90.0f;
private float cubeSpeedY = 1.0f;

public MyGLRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT1);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, lightDifuse, 0);

    cube = new Cube(gl, context);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) height = 1;
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glOrthof(-2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_POSITION, lightPosition, 0);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glRotatef(cubeAngleY, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cube.draw(gl);
    cubeAngleY += cubeSpeedY;
}
```

Comment: do you know whether GLUtils.texImage2D makes an RGB or RGBA texture? Do you have blending or alpha testing turned on?

Comment: I just have what you can see in this class, and the rest on the project its just the renderer. going to update the post with the renderer class

Comment: Im going to reply myself, the problem was that i got no implemented that on my renderer glEnable (GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); ty @user253751